# Use RELATED and FILTER to cross reference two tables in DAX?

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax

I have two tables in power pivot, a order header and a order detail.  I would like to identify on the header, with a true/false flag, if a particular class of item is on the order detail.

Order Header Table

```
Order ID    Order Amt   *Has HBG*
100041328   10.24        1
100041329   34.57        0
100041330   25.89        1
```

Order Detail Table

```
Order ID    SKU       Dept
100041328   1749988   HBG
100041328   9102272   SAC
100041329   1325344   SOA
100041329   4255337   LAF
100041329   7541744   SOC
100041330   7862194   HBG
100041330   3829646   HAS
100041330   3399937   EAR
```

I'm using the order ID to establish a relationship between the two tables.  I should think that some sort of combination of FILTER and RELATED would allow me to flagorder 100041328 and 100041330 as having products in the HBG department but I keep getting errors.  Any thoughts on how these could be flagged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can count the number of rows on the detail table using [COUNTROWS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634574.aspx) inside a [CALCULATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634825.aspx) statement which changes the row context to filter context. Add an additional filter for Dept and return 1 or 0 depending on how many entries have been found. You can display the 1 or 0 as True/False.

```
=
IF (
    CALCULATE (
        COUNTROWS ( DetailsTable ),
        DetailsTable[Dept] = "HBG"
    )
        > 0,
    1,
    0
)
```

Comment: Yep, that's exactly it!  Thanks.